# When should I use the verb to be in this way?

Tags: be

Sentence: WOW, an Icelandic budget airline, **is to** start fares from US to Ireland for less than $350 return, including all taxes.

[Source](http://www.irishcentral.com/culture/travel/WOW-350-round-trip-flights-from-US-to-Ireland-announced.html).

So, why did the writer use the infinitive form of the verb TO BE in that sentence? What's the meaning?

Also, for this example:

*Am I to believe in that?* x *Am I supposed to believe in that?* x *Should I believe in that?*

The first sentence above is the one that I don't get the meaning. Could anyone please what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

*...**is** to start fares...* (i.e. *to be* + infinitive) - in this context, the meaning is a formal expression of intent or obligation.

More typically, 'to be + infinitive' is used to express, imperiously, a command.   '*What am I supposed to do ?*  '*You are to attend the meeting at 3pm*

*Am I to believe ...* (i.e. interrogative *to be*  (especially first person) + infinitive) is an idiomatic, and imperious-sounding form whose sense, depending on context, includes '*Am I supposed to believe* ...', '*Do you expect me to believe*...', '*Is it really the case that...*', *'Are you honestly suggesting that...'*

Comment: Without evidence, I would not accept that _is to start_ is a contraction of _is going to start_. I agree that they are more and less formal ways of saying the same thing, but to describe one as a contraction of the other is a much stronger claim about their relationship.